# Creating a directed graph from an undirected graph with dfs_tree, but keep attributes

Tags: python, networkx

I want to force an undirected graph to a directed graph using a specific node as the root. I can do this using `dfs_tree()`:

```
G = nx.Graph([(0, 1, {"color": "red"}), (1, 2, {"color": "blue"}), (3, 2, {"color": "green"})])
DG = nx.dfs_tree(G, 0)
```

But the problem is that the attributes are lost in the process:

```
DG.edges(data=True)

OutEdgeDataView([(0, 1, {}), (1, 2, {}), (2, 3, {})])
```

Is there a different way to do this, where you don't lose the attributes? Or do I have to map them back manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have enough memory available, you can first create the `DiGraph` with all edges and then remove all, but the `dfs_edges`. This will preserve all attribute information. Alternatively, you could iterate over `dfs_edges` and retrieve the edge information to add the edge and the label to the directed graph.

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph([(0, 1, {"color": "red"}), (1, 2, {"color": "blue"}), (3, 2, {"color": "green"})])
DG = nx.DiGraph(G)

DG.remove_edges_from(DG.edges - nx.dfs_edges(G, 0))

print(DG.edges(data=True))
# [(0, 1, {'color': 'red'}), (1, 2, {'color': 'blue'}), (2, 3, {'color': 'green'})]
```

Comment: I do have enough memory, thankfully, because I am just processing a lot of small graphs. This works. Quite interesting because I didn't know that converting a undirected graph to a directed graph would automatically create a complimentary "reverse edge" so that the directed graph still behaves like an undirected one.